# Trouble writing results in a csv file

Tags: php, csv, curl, web-scraping

I've written a script in `php` to fetch links and write them in a csv file from the main page of wikipedia. The script does fetch the links accordingly. However, I can't write the populated results in a csv file. When I execute my script, It does nothing, no error either. Any help will be highly appreciated.

My try so far:

```
<?php
include "simple_html_dom.php";
$url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page";
function fetch_content($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
    $htmlContent = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $dom = new simple_html_dom();
    $dom->load($htmlContent);
    $links = array();
    foreach ($dom->find('a') as $link) {
        $links[]= $link->href . '<br>';
    }
    return implode("\n", $links);

    $file = fopen("itemfile.csv","w");
    foreach ($links as $item) {
        fputcsv($file,$item);
    }
    fclose($file);
}
fetch_content($url);
?>
```

Comment: Why are you adding `<br>` when this is being written to CSV file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.You are using `return` in your function, that's why nothing gets written in the file as code stops executing after that.

2.Simplified your logic with below code:-

```
$file = fopen("itemfile.csv","w");
foreach ($dom->find('a') as $link) {
  fputcsv($file,array($link->href));
}
fclose($file);
```

So the full code needs to be:-

```
<?php

   //comment these two lines when script started working properly
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors',1); // 2 lines are for Checking and displaying all errors
    include "simple_html_dom.php";
    $url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page";
    function fetch_content($url)
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
        $htmlContent = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $dom = new simple_html_dom();
        $dom->load($htmlContent);
        $links = array();
        $file = fopen("itemfile.csv","w");
        foreach ($dom->find('a') as $link) {
            fputcsv($file,array($link->href));
        }
        fclose($file);
    }
    fetch_content($url);
?>
```

Comment: @asmitu  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 0):

The reason the file does not get written is because you `return` out of the function before that code can even be executed.